# Create line use BoxView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I need to create a line which is a made up of multiple `BoxView`s (`WidthRequest=0.20830` and `HeightRequest=5` for every `BoxView`). There will be 1440 `BoxView`s in a sequence arranged in way that it will create a line(approximately  `WidthRequest=300`).

My Code -

```
public partial class timeManagement : ContentPage
{
    double oneMinute=0.20833333;
    public timeManagement ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout{Orientation=StackOrientation.Horizontal,                
        };

        for(int i=1;i<=14;i++)
        {
            BoxView piece_ofLine = new BoxView
            { 
                HeightRequest=5,
                WidthRequest=5,
                Color=Color.Red
            };

            if (i >= 5 && i <= 9) {
                stack.Children.Add (piece_ofLine);
                piece_ofLine.Color = Color.Green;
            } else {
                stack.Children.Add (piece_ofLine);
                piece_ofLine.Color = Color.Red;
            }

        }


        Content = new StackLayout {
            Padding =50, 
            Spacing=0,

            Children = {
                stack
            }
        };

    }
}
```

And output is-[image]

But I want all boxes side by side so it will appear like a single line.

Comment: RIP application. This will kill its layout performance. What's the question, anyway?

Comment: I am hoping this will show me a complete line of width will be 300 but its showing me complete blank page. How to meet this requirement ? I changed Stacklayout to Horizontal but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here

1. The default orientation for a `StackLayout` is `Vertical` so you would need to set that on the `stack` variable
2. You would need to create a new instance for each `BoxView` that you add to the stack. Otherwise it will just keep adding the same one over and over. And in the end you would just have one.
3. I assume that you would want them directly to the side of each other. If this is the case, I think that it would be safest to explicitly set the `Spacing` of your `StackLayout` to `0`

Comment: Yes you are right sir. I made changes and every new BoxView is overlapping on each other so I have one single BoxView now.

Comment: Now I create new instance for every BoxView but its appearing after bit of space. Even making spacing=0;

Comment: Thanks @David Pilkington, Finally your solution worked.